# N Connector - Best mount for PCB and how?

Tags: connector

Up until today i've ezperimented with antennas by basically taping the coax endpoint to my breadboards and it's been working "so so" and I'm looking for a PCB connector for my N Connector cable.

Any ideas what to get and how you connect those? Anything special to consider?

[image]

([source](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/65/N_Connector.jpg))

Comment: Probably the nearest you'll get http://www.pasternack.com/n-female-standard-thru-hole-pcb-connector-pe44398-p.aspx

Comment: $20 for a single PCB mount connector? Ouch :(

Comment: Yea that was a bit more expensive than I would imagine it would be considering the antenna itself cost only 30$, but it would be worth it if i could solder it in place and get rid of disconnects because of the temporary fix i have today.. Ugh, 4 connectors tho? or just soldering points?

Comment: @Torxed do you have to use N connectors?

Comment: Are you stuck with using type N? SMA connectors are generally available in the $5 range, but can't handle as much power as type N.

Comment: Actually i'm not sure, was just looking on SMA connectors but as i don't have any connectors infront of me i can't test and see what i actually need, which is a problem. I just know the cable-mounting alias and that's a "N connector", by looking on the SMA connectors it might fit. How do you apply power to/connect the SMA? I only find mounting measurements for them and i'm quite new on this whole thing but seeing how there's no place to be tought this where i'm from i'm diving in to it on my own. Any good forums for silly beginner questions perhaps?

Comment: This was the SMA connector i found btw which appears to be a suitable fit: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Antenna-Connector-SMA-female-Right-Angle-PCB-Mount-/360199510250

Comment: @Torxed You just need a male SMA connector to go with that female - happy mating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to follow up on the comments.  Most people don't mount a big N connector on a PCB edge because it would flex the PCB too much.  Inside an enclosure you could mount the the N on a panel then cable over to the PCB.  An edge mount PCB SMA connector is a good choice, just make sure the gap matches the PCB thickness that you are using.

[image: SMA edge]

As mentioned by several people in the comments SMA is usually a preferred option.  They have very high frequency responses to 18GHz (which matches Type-N) and sometimes higher and you can buy good cables for them.  Typical curves for a new clean Type N connector with a perfect load (VSWR=1.0) give limits of ≈5000 W at 20 MHz and ≈500 W at 2 GHz.  Compared to SMA which is about 500W @ 100Mhz and 170W at 1GHz.

I use them so often I put N-SMA adapters on my equipment and use all SMA cables.

[image: n-sma]
[image: SMA]

Also for "launching" or tying into a an area of a PCB I use simi-rigid SMA coax.  This is basically a "pipe" where the outside is copper is hard and good for soldering down to the PCB ground plane in either a large area or a few spots.  The center conductor is kept short as possible to get to the test point.  This provides strain relief and a very few reflections across the band to about 6Ghz, sometimes higher if you're careful.

[image: pigtail]

Comment: I'm happy with that explanation!
I'll snoop around for a beginner forum but for now, this is just what i need to get started in my understanding of radio tech (been eager to learn this for 15 years now)!

Comment: @Torxed try the rf cafe http://www.rfcafe.com

Comment: i'll try to figure out that site, to me it just looks like one of those advertising sites you end up by a random google accident (just a TON of text and advertisements) :/